# Inline UDF in Group By SQL

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, inline, scalar

I'm trying to design a function to replace a large case statement of commonly used logic in many stored procedures.

Based on my research, I've set it up as a Inline table valued function.

My question is: Many of the stored procedures i'll be replacing are using Group By's but I can't seem to group on an Inline function like I can a scalar. How do you group by on an inline function ? I think i'm trying to accomplish this:

```
SELECT  account
,       (SELECT Inline FROM fnGroups (id)) AS Buckets
,       SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM    FactTable
GROUP BY 
        Account
,       (SELECT Inline FROM fnGroups (id)) --Not Allowed
```

There are many stored procedures that need this update and i'm trying to make this function as dynamic as possible, and avoid minor re-writes to each stored procedure. I've tried a scalar version however the performance is suffering quite a bit.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` should do the job:

```
SELECT  f.account
,       a.Inline 
,       SUM(f.Sales) AS Sales
FROM    FactTable f
OUTER APPLY fnGroups(f.id) a
GROUP BY 
        f.Account
        a.Inline
```

More examples with `APPLY` : http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Comment: This works great, thank you. I hadn't used the APPLY function yet. This seems to be the cleanest way to make these changes. Great article as well.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery should work if it's just the aggregate and group by that throws it:

```
SELECT account,
,      Buckets
,      SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM (
    SELECT  account
    ,       Sales
    ,       (SELECT Inline FROM fnGroups (id)) AS Buckets
    FROM    FactTable) F
GROUP BY 
        Account
,       Buckets
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm trying not to change the structure of the code since there's so many that need updating. It may not be possible and i'll have to stick with the scalar version, I wanted to make sure i'm not missing something obvious in using the inline.